# Can you traverse Site-to-Site VPNs

Tags: vpn, networking

For example:

```
Router A <-> Site-To-Site VPN <-> Router B <-> Site-to-Site VPN <-> Router C
```

If static routes were put in place so that:

`Router A` doesn't know about `Router C LAN Subnet`, but I static route tells is that `Router B` knows, it sends traffic to `Router B`, `Router B` sends that traffic down the tunnel to `Router C.`

`Router C` replies, it doesn't know about `Router A LAN Subnet`, but it knows via Static Routes that `Router B` knows, it sends traffic to `Router B`, `Router B` sends it down the VPN tunnel to `Router A`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If this wasn't the case, site-to-site VPNs wouldn't be very useful, would it?

Yes, it's possible, and generally they way they're set up.  They are simply an encrypted "tunnel" between two routers, and unless there are rules in place to treat it differently, the VPN traffic is treated just like any other once it arrives at the destination site, and that can certainly include being forwarded onto another site, if that's where the traffic needs to go.

Answer (score 0):

Not only is this possible, it is standard. For the router a VPN is not different than a physical connection and those form that funny thing called "internet" where a packet may traverse a lot of such routers from the beginning to the end of it's journey.

Comment: Although that came across very condescending, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

With your EXACT example...possibly.

The problem is introducing site-to-site VPN complicates things, especially if those site-to-site VPNs have policies in place that only allow traffic to/from certain subnets.  You can set them to just be route based and not mess with policies that restrict traffic, but a lot of times they do have policies in place as such.

Most likely a network won't have ONLY site-to-site VPN tunnels, to where Router A's default 0.0.0.0/0 route is going out the tunnel.  IF router B has routes to both Router A and Router C...AND Router C has its default route sending to Router B...AND there are no restrictive policies on the tunnels...then yes it should work.

HOWEVER, it is VERY RARE that this setup would be in place like this.  Most tunnels have source/destination restrictions in place for the tunnel AND most people don't use VPN tunnels for their default routes, unless they don't have separate internet connections at those locations.

Comment: Why would it need to be a default route? A static route on Router C sending traffic for that necessary subnet to Router B would work. The default route sending everything else to the "Internet"

Comment: You said in your op that C doesn't know about A, hence no static route.  If it doesn't then it would have to look for it via it's default route.

Comment: BTW, this whole time we've been discussing routes as if only static or default existed.  When we throw dynamic routing into the mix, assuming routers A,B, and C are all participating in these routes, then that's different, but also negates your "C doesn't know about A" parts.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would draw that picture differently (vertical only because horizontal was getting too wide):

```
Host Zebra
     |
(Router A LAN) 
     |
Router A
     |
(Site-To-Site VPN)
     |
Router B
     |
(Site-to-Site VPN)
     |
Router C
     |
(Router C LAN)
     |
Host Alligator
```

Each machine makes decisions based on what it knows, and you indicated that Router A doesn't know about Router C LAN, and Router C doesn't know about Router A LAN

- Zebra is presumably configured with Router A as its default route. 
  It will send packets destined for Host Alligator to Router A over
  Router A LAN.
- This next hop is where you potentially get into
  trouble.  Router A doesn't know about Router C LAN, so its best guess
  to get to Host Alligator is its default route.  If that default route
  is over the VPN to Router B, everyone is happy.  This configuration is typically
  called a full tunnel in contrast to "split" or "split-horizon" VPN
  tunnels where Router A would have a default route to the Internet.

If Router A's default route is Router B, then the message will get to Host Alligator.  But you run into the same question on the way back from Host Alligator to Host Zebra, unless Router C's default route is also Router B.

Another way to address the issue is to implement a routing protocol between the routers.  Then they all chat with each other about all of the networks they can reach, and you might not need static routes at all.  But routing protocols are sometimes challenging to set up and secure, so that's another topic.